# FlutterAppRequiredException:The current directory does not appear to be a Flutter application project

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-tools

I am trying to install Flutterfire CLI on Firebase CLI, I followed the [instructions from the Firebase website](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-auth-in-flutter-apps#2). The error is:

> FlutterAppRequiredException: The current directory does not appear to be a Flutter application project.

I ran all the steps up to `firebase projects:list` but after that, I got the same error while running `flutterfire configure`.

I tried changing my directory to my project directory using `cd D:\Individual\Ayush\Apps` but after that, it still showed the same thing.

Comment: From the error message is seems that you're running the `flutterfire` command in a directory that does not contain a Flutter app.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen But when I changed my directory to the folder that contains the Flutter app it doesn't change the path to the specified directory and I ended up with the same error.